# How can I perform Federated Learning on different dataset files having same output feature but different input feature?

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I’m apply federated learning on several datasets,having similar output feature but different input features, how cany I do that. By feature I mean columns in the dataset. I want to know is this even possible to do? Please provide a comprehensive answer?